# hosting asmx web service in .net 2.0 clr without iis

Tags: .net, soap, asmx

I have .net 2.0 asmx service. Have windows xp sp2 without IIS, with .net 2.0.
I know about hosting wcf server in your app, but it's only in 3.5 framework.
i have no right to install higer .net or iis on this machine.
How i can easily host that service, maybe some known libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compile the `WebService` with .NET 2.0 instead of 3.5 or 4.0 and you should be able to host it inside your IIS.

[Here is an example](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/010430.htm) on how to create and host a Web Service using .NET 2.0 and IIS.

**Update**

Since you don't have IIS and probably Can't install it, you can use [Web Matrix](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17278), it's not a software that should be use to host your web services permanently, but it's very ideal when you develop web applications. You don't even need administration priviliges since it uses ports above 1024.

Comment: actually, dont have iis installed

Comment: Oh, without IIS! Updated my Answer.